# Laravel: validate ajax request

Tags: ajax, laravel, validation, request

In my laravel application, I am loading the forms via ajax request. I need to validate every method, such as `create` & `edit`, to be only the `ajax request`. But if they are called via `get` then they should be redirected with an error message.

I am using the following code. Its working fine but I have to write it on every method which I need to protect.

*SomeController.php, AnotherController.php, YetAnotherController.php, ...:*

```php
public function create()
{
    if(!request()->ajax())
    {
        # setting error message
        session()->flash('warning', 'Invalid request method or method not allowed');

        # redirecting
        return redirect()->route("admin.dashboard");
    }

    ...
}

public function edit()
{
    if(!request()->ajax())
    {
        # setting error message
        session()->flash('warning', 'Invalid request method or method not allowed');

        # redirecting
        return redirect()->route("admin.dashboard");
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there a way to validate the specified methods for every controller in the application..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller.php's __construct add this:

```
public function __construct ()
{
    $ajaxMethods = ['insert', 'update'];

    $currentActionMethod = Route::getCurrentRoute ()->getActionMethod ();

    if ( in_array ( $currentActionMethod, $ajaxMethods ) AND ! request ()->ajax () )
    {
        return redirect ()->back ()->with ( 'warning', 'Invalid request method or method not allowed' );
    }
}
```

**Or** 
Create a middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $ajaxMethods = ['insert', 'update'];

    $currentActionMethod = Route::getCurrentRoute ()->getActionMethod ();

    if ( in_array ( $currentActionMethod, $ajaxMethods ) AND ! request ()->ajax () )
    {
        return redirect ()->back ()->with ( 'warning', 'Invalid request method or method not allowed' );
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @OmerYILMAZ, It works. I am posting my final code to make it easy for newbie like me. Thanks again.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a middleware, validate it and call the middleware in the constructor of the controller

Answer (score 0):

one way in to add it to your helper,so the only thing you should is first create a validation method in your helper.php, then defined it in your autoload section in your composer.json and finish.
call your function anywhere you want. let me know if you want example or have question about it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @OmerYILMAZ and others who helped, here is my final code...

*app\Http\Middleware\AllowedAjaxRequests.php:*

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class AllowedAjaxRequests
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        # variables
        $ajaxMethods   = ['create', 'update'];
        $currentAction = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionMethod();

        # validating request method
        if (in_array($currentAction, $ajaxMethods) && !$request->ajax())
        {
            # setting error message
            session()->flash('warning', 'Invalid request method or method not allowed');

            # redirecting
            return redirect()->route("admin.dashboard");
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

*app\Http\Kernel.php:*

```php
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    ...

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...

        'ajaxRequests' => \App\Http\Middleware\AllowedAjaxRequests::class,
    ];

    ...
}
```

*routes\web.php:*

```php
Route::middleware(['ajaxRequests'])->group(function() {
    ...
});
```